# angularjs saving null values asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

i am getting data in my dropdown by using ajax,I am saving data to database from dropdown by using angularjs. When i insert data, its saving null value in table.

ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "/Official/GetDivision",
                                datatype: "Json",
                                success: function (data) {

                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                        var opt = new Option(data[i].division);
                                        $("#division").append(opt);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetDivision()
        {
            var division = db.Depts.GroupBy(x => x.Division)
                           .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

            return Json(division);
        }
```

Html

```
 <select ng-model="empModel.division" id="division" name="Division" class="form-control" >
                                <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                            </select>
```

Angularjs

```
$scope.saveCustomer = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Official/InsertEmployee',
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.empModel),
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function () {
                console.log($scope.empModel);
                swal("Saved", "Data Imported Successfully", "success")
                GetAllData();
                });
        };
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult InsertEmployee([FromBody] Official emp)
        {
            db.Officials.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(emp);
        }
```

angular saving null value of dropdown, everything looks fine for me dont know what is the issue

Comment: didnt get you, which official object?

Comment: i dont understand from where i can get this object?

Comment: just noticed in your drop down you don't have `value` set perhaps that's your problem?

Comment: what should i write in value? i am saving this data i think "name" is therr for dropdown....

Comment: the `name` just relates to the attribute name that it binds to, which I don't even think you need since ng-model does it. the value in the option is what actually set's the value so you get null because there is no value.

Comment: so what should i write in value?

Comment: write `value="foo"` see if it shows in your controller.